# prevent all users from deleting a specific cloudformation stack

Tags: json, security, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, policy

I have this IAM Policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack"
            ],
            "Resource": "MystackARN"
        }
    ]
}
```

I attached it to my user to test it then tried to delete the cloudformation stack, then I got this error:

```
Failed to delete stack: User: arn:aws:iam::accountId:user/me is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DeleteStack on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:stackARN
```

I want for all users except me getting this error when they try to delete the stack specified inside the policy.

Is there any way using `AWS CLI` to add this policy to all users except me (stack owner)?

**OR:**

Is there any way to remove the permission `DeleteStack` from all users except me (stack owner)?

I tried this:

```
aws iam attach-user-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::AccountId:policy/cfn-policy --user-name arn:aws:iam::AccountId:user/*
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way to achieve this is:

1. Creating an *IAM Group* and attaching your Deny policy to it
2. Add all users except yourself to the group

This would be the AWS recommended way of doing it.

Comment: I have applied this strategy to  protect the stacks. It's working very fine. But I have a question, what happens when I add a new AWS User? that user will be able to delete/update the stack. is therer any workaround?

Comment: Add the user to the correct group. An IAM user by default does not have any permissions so the onus is on YOU